# Why will the exit() function not be called in d3 v5?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I want to update the legend of my scatterplot, every time I update the data. The enter() method is called, but the exit() method not. For now I only use two arrays and switch back and forth between them.

I have a initSG(), where I initialize global variables. A drawSVG() function, where I draw the plot including the legend. And a updateData() method, where I redraw with new data.

```
legend; legendG;

initSVG(){
    this.legendG = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend-g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 130 + ',0)');
}

drawSVG() {
...
    this.legend = this.legendG.selectAll('.legend')
      .data(this.color.domain())
      .enter().append('g')
...
}

updateData() {
...
    this.legend = this.legendG.selectAll('.legend')
      .data(this.color.domain())
      .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend');

    this.legend.exit().remove(); 
... 
}
```

This way enter() works, but if I do change the updateData() methods this way as I have seen here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218
the 'g's are appended not the first time I call the updateData() method but the second time:

```
updateData() {
...
    this.legend = this.legendG.selectAll('.legend')
      .data(this.color.domain());

    this.legend.exit().remove(); 

    this.legend.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend');

... 
}
```

Even if I leave out the exit() method. I don't understand why it makes a difference. Also it still is not exiting the 'g's, which should should be gone.

Comment: i agree with it, its hard use update and exit for me too, so i avoid it, and start using remove and call redraw back

Comment: @KEKUATAN can you give me a quick example for that?

Comment: What if you try merging the `enter()` elements? Maybe add ` .merge(this.legend)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there is no reason to split initial drawing and redrawing. Simply 1) apply data and save the `update` selection, 2) call `enter` upon update selection, append new elements and set initial / data independent attributes, 3) merge enter and update selections (looks like you forgot this one), 4) set data dependent attributes 5) remove exit selection items.

I don't see why `legend` is being saved -- it should suffice to be a function local variable.

Don't use `attr('class', 'legend')`, instead use `classed('legend', true)`. Classed has a plus in that it operates on one class at a time -- if you use attr, it overwrites all classes. Same with style; use `style` instead of `attr`

This bit of code

```
this.legend = this.legendG.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(this.color.domain())
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend');

this.legend.exit().remove();
```

doesn't work, because `this.legend` refers to **enter selection** -- it doesn't contain any stale elements (since its job is to have only new ones), and thus nothing is removed.

This bit of code

```
this.legend = this.legendG.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(this.color.domain());

this.legend.exit().remove(); 

this.legend.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend');
```

likely doesn't work, because d3 reuses same dom elements (since by default if id is not specified, it simply uses order), but you're not utilizing update selection. If new data has same length as the old, the `enter` selection would be empty.